# Accessing value of empty key in javascript object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

`Javascript` objects can accept an empty key with some value but how do we access the value of that empty key ?

```
var obj = {
    "": "Name"
}
```

Comment: You could use `obj[""]`

Comment: Any other way apart from that?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```js
var obj = {"":"abc"};
console.log(obj[""]);
```